# Is it possible to delay the "bool" test in a Dictionary<string, Func<bool, object>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I have a `Dictionary<string, Func<bool, object>>` I would like to conditionally loop through the dictionary and add the "object" only if `bool == true`.
But I'm not sure how to pass `pair.Value()` as a bool.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Func<bool, object>> pair in parameters)
{   
    //error pair.Value(), Delegate Func has 1 parameter(s) but is invoked with 0 arguments.  
    //pair.Value(true) obviously works, but defeats the purpose

    if (pair.Value() != null)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value());
    } 
}
```

Should I use `Expression<Func<bool, object>>` and compile/evaluate the bool.    If so, how?

Comment: You show *exactly* how to pass the delegate a boolean right in your question, so clearly you *do* know how to do it.

Comment: it's a little confusing what you are asking for. are you trying to add an entry of the object if something is true,

Comment: there is no `bool` in `Func<bool, object>`: it represents a function that takes a bool as input

Comment: Yes, I want to evaluate that bool in the pair.Value(bool) expression.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Robert4Real No, it makes no sense to evaluate the boolean that it accepts as a parameter.  There is no boolean until you provide one, which means you had to have already evaluated it from some source other than the delegate.  What you get out of evaluating the delegate is an `object`, not a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

I get it you want to store a condition that will be resolved later when you go to pull it so what you really need is this kind of dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, Func<object>> dictionary= new Dictionary<string, Func<object>>()
```

and you would add entries like this

```
dictionary.Add("key", () => /*Insert your condition here*/ 3 == 2 ? /*If True*/ obj : /*If False*/ null );
```

and then your code works perfectly

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Func<object>> pair in dictionary)
{     
    if (pair.Value() != null)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value());
}
```

**EDIT**

excellent then here is 2 options you have:

**Option 1**

you make this Dictionary

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<bool>>();
```

then you add like this

```
dictionary.Add("key", condition => { if (condition) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("key", obj); });
```

now your logic becomes this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Action<bool>> pair in dictionary)
            pair.Value(bool);
```

**Option 2**

it looks like what you really want is this

```
var list = new List<Action<bool>>();
list.Add(condition => { if (condition) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("key", obj) });
```

and then your logic would look like this

```
list.ForEach(x => x(bool));
```

Comment: Almost.  I would ideally like to have a bool parameter passed into the function.  So instead of calling it If (pair.Value() != null), I would like to call it just "if (pair.Value(bool))", without a test for NULL.

Comment: What I really would like is a 3 dimensional dictionary, something like Dictionary<string, bool, object>   If the bool == true, then AddWithValue(pair.Key, pair.Value).  But something like that doesn't exist, unless I use TUPLES.

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote for providing a thoughtful explanation, unlike some of the other useless comments on this thread.  However, it's not my ideal solution because I can't expose the cmd parameter outside of the function that has the "foreach".  That needs to remain an implementation detail, so I just wanted to pass a 3 dimensional dictionary like I mentioned above, just a key, condition, and object, no additional Actions.

Comment: Thanks alright that seems resonable. I got 2 ways of dealing with those